# how to use *ngIf 'not equal to' for checking condition

Tags: angular

Is it possible to use `!=` in `ngIf`?
I have tried but it didn't work:

```
<div class="tranDetails tenPadding"  *ngIf="transDtlsObj?.txnHistory!='null'">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

null is not equal to 'null', regardless of whether you use != or !==.
*ngIf works fine for != operations, try removing the quotes in your code,that could  be the issue,

```
<div class="tranDetails tenPadding"  *ngIf="transDtlsObj?.txnHistory!=null">
```